# Why doesn't timer's time_step work?

Tags: python

I set a float property for the time_step (bpy.context.scene.time_step), and initialized a timer using this code:

```
def execute(self, context):    
    wm = context.window_manager
    self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(time_step=bpy.context.scene.time_step, window=context.window)
```

When I print the time deltas between ticks `(now - time.time())`, they are `~0.0001`. How can I change the time_step correctly?
I even tried to set it with a constant, without any luck.